# Converting a ASCII value into its corresponding Integer value

Tags: c#, char, ascii

The objective of this code is to *add* all the integers in a whole number into one value (e.g `"2013" => 6`),
In c# I have written the code so it outputs the number to its corresponding ASCII value one at a time, but I am at a loss at how to convert it back into its *number value*.

Note that I am new at C#

```
        string Year;
        int Total = 0;
        int Adding = 0;
        int Adding2 = 0;

        Console.WriteLine("Write The year you want converted");
        Year = Console.ReadLine();

        for (int i = 0; i < Year.Length; i++)
        {
            Adding2 = Year[i];
            Adding = Convert.ToInt32(Adding2);
            Total = Adding + Total;
            
            Console.WriteLine(Total);
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

You should sum *values*, not *ascii codes*:

```
    ...

    for (int i = 0; i < Year.Length; i++)
    {
        Adding2 = Year[i];
        Adding = Adding2 - '0';
        Total = Adding + Total;
    }

    Console.WriteLine(Total);
```

In *general case*, you can use [char.GetNumericValue()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.char.getnumericvalue?view=net-6.0):

```
    // double: some characters have fractional values: '⅝'
    double Total = 0.0;

    foreach (char c in Year) {
      double value = char.GetNumericValue(c);

      // If character has value (e.g. 'A' doesn't have) 
      if (value != -1)
        Total += value;
    } 

    Console.WriteLine(Total);
```

Comment: Note that both approaches would need explicit input validation for the cases of non-digits in a real application, as they otherwise give nonsensical results without complaining.